# How to merge PDF with FDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fdf

I have an FDF file generated after filing a html form, and of course a PDF template, my question is how to merge those two files in PHP and return the PDF to the user? I can't use PDFTK because I am hosting my website on a free provider.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do client-side merge, by sending the FDF to the client. The FDF has the /F key pointing at the Base PDF (aka Template).

If you need server-side merging, you can either use some of the libraries floating around (such as iText or pdflib), and stitch together your merger, or you can use existing merging utilities, such as FDFMerge by Appligent, which would be very easy to integrate (because it is a command line application).

However, for a server-side merger, you'd have to see what you actually can install on your server. If you can install libraries, fine; if you can install applications, fine too; if it is too difficult to do that, you have to rely on client-side merging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am only looking for server-side merge without command line as I am using a free hosting service. I found PdfNet, but I need to install it first and I can't do it. A php portable library is the only solution I think.

Comment: Then you may end up with a problem, and have to reconsider your hosting arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [SetaPDF-FormFiller component](http://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-formfiller/details/) (not free!). It's a PHP library allowing you to fill in Acro- and/or XFA forms in pure PHP.